# Why doesn't page source update to show page response?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to do a little testing on what I can find in the page source of a Google Translate request. For example, I would like to translate "Hola" from Spanish to English, so I type Hola in the source language text box and translate this to English using Google Translate. I want to then see if I can find "Hola" or "Hello" in the page source, but I cannot find them using the most basic form of search (Ctrl+F).

To try to get around this I look for things around the text boxes to give me an idea of where the text should be. However, I am having no luck.

Is this something that could be done? Or is Google hiding "Hola" and "Hello" behind the scenes?

The link to the translation is [here](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/hola)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page source would not show what you type into a textbox. I'm not sure the reasoning you have behind this but to find the code for what you type into the textbox, just right click 'inspect' and you can see the translated text appears in

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en"><span class="">Hello</span></span>
```

Comment: +1 learning to use the browser developer tools is key. Not only can you get rendered html information, but also any calls that the page is making to the server.